# How to implement per-page authorization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails has some very good methods for role based authorization, e.g., [cancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

But how can you grant authorization to specific pages, rather than controllers/actions.

For example, take the case of an app that contains a receipt or invoice model. A User can log in and generate an invoice. The User then needs to send his customer a URL to that invoice. The customer should not be able to access invoices of other customers, particularly important as Rails generates sequential and easily guessable path names (e.g., /invoices/1, /invoices/2, etc.).

Ideally the customer should not need to signup to view these pages. One solution might be to generate a random password on Invoice creation, and send this to the customer to unlock that page specific page.

This sounds like an issue that should be reasonably common, but after Googling I have not found much information of use (though I may be using incorrect search terms).

So I would like to know:

1. Is this something I should be attempting with Rails?
2. Are there any gems or example apps that I could study?
3. What are the potential considerations/ pitfalls of this approach?

Comment: if the customer has to sign in for viewing his `invoice` then you can create a custom method to check if the `invoice` is delivered to `current_user` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if the user you wish to have access was registered in the system it would be no issue at all as you could generate a permission record.

How ever your concern with the predictable urls can be easily solved by :
FriendlyID(https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)
or my personal favourite
Vanity permalinks (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally the customer should not need to signup to view these pages. One solution might be to generate a random password on Invoice creation, and send this to the customer to unlock that page specific page.

So anyone with the information should be able to access it. One solution is to obfuscate the url or use a UUID, so don't give out `/invoices/1`, instead give `/invoices/8a20ae59-30d5-41b6-86d3-ac66e3b43e9d`. The url is unguessable. Still the url is the only piece of information one needs to access the contents.

If you want two-factor authorization, then the easiest way is to use http basic auth, generate a password from the url and your secret_base, and send it to the user separately. As it's generated, you don't need to store it, you can always check it by generating it again.

Comment: Thanks @rewritten, this is a good idea. I will give this is shot and report back